# Multiple environments with one cluster sharing the same terraform state

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-eks

I have created EKS cluster using terraform-aws-modules/vpc/aws with Terraform, I use one VPC with 3 private subnets on each AZs in Frankfurt. I've created two services (tomcat and psql) and deployment which are exposed via LoadBalancer and accessible via internet. It looks fine so far.
but the problem is that it's only one environment (DEV). I would like to create multiple environments like stage,test and more inside one VPC and inside one cluster, how to do it using terraform? should I create new files per environment? It would not make sense but nothing comes to my mind... I was considering also workspaces but the problem is that new workspace requires new state - it means that I need to create new VPC with new cluster per one workspace! maybe I should divide my terraform files to have something like "general" workspace and there would be a configuration to VPC and cluster, and create new workspaces for each of the environments? do you have any ideas or better solutions?

```
                   VPC - 172.26.0.0/16
+----------------------+----------------------------------+
|                                                         |
|                                                         |
|                 KUBERNETES CLUSTER                      |
|    +-------------------------------------------------+  |
|    |                                                 |  |
|    |                                                 |  |
|    |                                                 |  |
|    | +------------------+       +-----------------+  |  |
|    | |                  |       |                 |  |  |
|    | |     TEST ENV     |       |     DEV ENV     |  |  |
|    | | +------+ +-----+ |       | +-----+ +-----+ |  |  |
|    | | |tomcat| |psql | |       | |tomcat |psql | |  |  |
|    | | +------+ +-----+ |       | +-----+ +-----+ |  |  |
|    | |                  |       |                 |  |  |
|    | +------------------+       +-----------------+  |  |
|    |                                                 |  |
|    |                                                 |  |
|    |                                                 |  |
|    |                                                 |  |
|    |                                                 |  |
|    |                                                 |  |
|    +-------------------------------------------------+  |
|                                                         |
+---------------------------------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to create multiple environments in a single K8s cluster. You could use [namespace](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/working-with-objects/namespaces/) for this. To access the different environments from outside the cluster, you can use a different domain name for each environment.

For example `dev.abc.com` to access the development environment and `test.abc.com` to access the test environment.

Comment: it doesn't help me... I wrote already - I use terraform, how do you want to manage terraform and k8s namespaces under one terraform state? let's say that we have one service where I need to define on which namespace it should be deployed. if I would go with your way, I could use only one environment

Comment: Terraform is used to maintain the infra side. You can use tools such as helm or kustomize to build yamls for your different environments

Comment: https://codefresh.io/helm-tutorial/helm-deployment-environments/ This article explains setting up multiple environments with helm

Answer (score 0):

You can "separate the vpc" in its own state file. And then have a workspace for each EKS cluster. For the EKS you can pull the VPC info one of two ways, either from AWS data source by tag or from the state file.

Your tree structure would look something like this:

```
├── vpc
│   ├── main.tf
│   └── outputs.tf
└── eks
    └── main.tf
```

Add the following to the backend settings in `vpc/main.tf`:

```
terraform {
  backend "s3" {
    ...
    key                  = "vpc/terraform.tfstate"
    workspace_key_prefix = "vpc"
    ...
  }
}
```

and `eks/main.tf`:

```
terraform {
  backend "s3" {
    ...
    key                  = "eks/terraform.tfstate"
    workspace_key_prefix = "eks"
    ...
  }
}
```

Passing the VPC to the EKS section:

Option 1 (pull from aws data source by name, ref https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/data-sources/vpc):

```
  data "aws_vpc" "selected" {
    filter {
      ...
    }
  }
```

Option 2 (pull from state file):

```
data "terraform_remote_state" "vpc" {
  backend = "s3"

  config = {
    ...
    key                  = "vpc/terraform.tfstate"
    workspace_key_prefix = "vpc"
    ...
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not a good practice to manage your applications inside terraform, you can use terraform just to create your cluster (infra) EC2, EKS, VPC.... but what inside the cluster, you can use helm/kubectl.... to manage your pods, for example you can have two repositories, one for terraform iac and the other for projects, then you can manage your environments ( dev, staging, prod...) by namespaces...